# problem with quick search android

Tags: android

Hi i'm trying to set up a quick search for my application but i only get a ClassNotFoundException after clicking the search button. I just want to show the user input in a Log. Here's what i got so far:

**Manifets.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".SearchActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                       android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

        <!-- declare the default searchable Activity for the whole app -->  
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                    android:value=".SearchActivity"/>
```

**searchable.xml**

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/search_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

**SearchActivity.java**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.searchresults);

        final Intent queryIntent = getIntent();
        final String queryAction = queryIntent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(queryAction)) {
            String searchKeywords = queryIntent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Log.i("YOU ENTERED", searchKeywords);
        }
    }
```

What i'm i doing wrong? Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks!!

**EDIT**: here is the log file:

```
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{se.madcoderz.searchExample/se.madcoderz.searchExample.SearchActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: se.madcoderz.searchExample.SearchActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/se.madcoderz.searchExample-2.apk]
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: se.madcoderz.searchExample.SearchActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/se.madcoderz.searchExample-2.apk]
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
01-18 13:34:03.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28349):     ... 11 more
```

The SDK version i'm using is 1.6

Comment: Can you provide the logcat output?

Comment: these kind of problem may occur in Android version 2.2,please check your sdk version is't 2.2 or some thing else.

Answer (score 1):

Well i solved my own problem. In the Mainefest.xml i changed the activity name to `<activity android:name=".searchExample.SearchActivity">` i did the same in the meta-data outside the activity:

```
<!-- declare the default searchable Activity for the whole app -->  
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                    android:value=".searchExample.SearchActivity"/>
```

the thing is that android defines the package name in the Manifest under **Manifest General Attributes** and i changed some packages names in my project, but the manifest didn't got updated with my changes. So that's why i had to add this ".searchExample" which is the last name in the package where this activity is.

But anyways this is also the reason why we have to add a dot at the start of an activity name in the manifest, which i hadn't until today.

Comment: This greatly helped me. I also had the same issue, qualifying the Activity with full package name helped.